# calculating Lempel-Ziv (LZ) complexity (aka sequence complexity) of a binary string

Tags: algorithm, binary, compression, complexity-theory, sequence

I need to calculate the LZ-complexity of a binary string. The LZ-complexity is the number of differencet substrings encountered as the stream is viewed from begining to the end. As an example:

s = 1001111011000010

Marking in the different substrings the sequence complexity c(s) = 6:
s = 1 / 0 / 01 / 1110 / 1100 / 0010 /

can someone guide me to find a simple solution for that? I am sure there should be some very straight-forward implementations for this well-known problem, but I have difficulty finding them. Can it be done simply done with constructing a suffix tree or something similar. If yes, exactly how? and what should I do?

anyone knows of any c/c++ source code to accomplish the task?

thanks in advance.

to clarify the construction of the tree suggested in the answers. Does the tree looks like this?

```
         o
       /   \
      o     o
     / \   / \
    o   o o   o
       /     /
      o     o
```

Answer (score 2):

@Arash and @Sanchit Gupta: You might've got confused between LZ76 complexity and LZ78 complexity. The one Arash is refering to is LZ76 complexity and the other one is LZ78 complexity. You can refer to section-3 of the paper "Estimating the Entropy Rate of Spike Trains via Lempel-Ziv Complexity".

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick example of how to compute LZ-Complexity using a tree.  For convenience - mine; not yours - this code implements a fixed-sized pre-allocated tree, and is a prime example of why void* pointers are ugly to use and difficult to maintain.  Hand this code in as is, and your lecturer is likely to shoot you in the face :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int LZComplexity(char *p_binarySequence, int p_maxTreeNodes)
{
 void **patternTree;
 void **currentNode;
 void **nextFreeNode;
 int nodeCount;
 int sequenceIndex;
 int currentDigit;

 nodeCount = 0;
 patternTree = malloc(sizeof(void*) * (p_maxTreeNodes << 1));
 currentNode = patternTree;
 nextFreeNode = patternTree + (sizeof(void*) << 1);
 currentNode[0] = NULL;
 currentNode[1] = NULL;
 sequenceIndex = 0;

 while (p_binarySequence[sequenceIndex])
 {
  currentDigit = p_binarySequence[sequenceIndex] - 48;
  if (NULL == currentNode[currentDigit])
  {
   currentNode[currentDigit] = nextFreeNode;
   nextFreeNode[0] = NULL;
   nextFreeNode[1] = NULL;
   nextFreeNode += (sizeof(void*) << 1);
   currentNode = patternTree;
   nodeCount++;
  }
  else
  {
   currentNode = currentNode[currentDigit];
  }
  sequenceIndex++;
 }

 free(patternTree);
 return nodeCount;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf("%u\n", LZComplexity("10100101001011101011", 1000));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Taliadon for taking the time to write the code, well I personally have no problem with void pointers! ;) to me your code looks quite ok! :D but was just wondering that for example I wrote should I get the LZ-complexity as 6 or 8?! your code and a manual construction of the tree suggests 8 but I have read that it should be 6, any comments on that?

Comment: if you have compilation errors just make two simple type casts form (void*) to (void **) and that should work!

Answer (score 1):

1 0 01 11 10 110 00 010
Complexity of sequence is 8 because the partitions are 8 not 6 - 1/0/01/11/10/110/00/010

Comment: well the LZ complexity of the string is not really calculated as you pointed out. It's different and for the above example it's 6 not 8 :-)

Comment: below is slightly modified code for catering open sequence i.e. sequences with not distinct last LZ pattern... it solved my problem to calculate LZ complexity according to paper   On Lempel-Ziv Complexity of Sequences
Ali Do˘ganaksoy1,2,4 and Faruk G¨olo˘glu2,3

Comment: int flag;
 while (p_binarySequence[sequenceIndex])
 {
  currentDigit = p_binarySequence[sequenceIndex] - 48;
  if (NULL == currentNode[currentDigit])
  {
   currentNode[currentDigit] = nextFreeNode;
   nextFreeNode[0] = NULL;
   nextFreeNode[1] = NULL;
   nextFreeNode += (sizeof(void*) << 1);
   currentNode = patternTree;
   nodeCount++;
flag=0;
  }
  else
  {
   currentNode = currentNode[currentDigit];
flag=1;
  }
  sequenceIndex++;
 }

 free(patternTree);
  if(flag==0) return nodeCount;
 else return nodeCount+1;
}

Comment: @Arash I read this paper and got LZ complexity 8  :)                     "On Lempel-Ziv Complexity of Sequences"
Ali Do˘ganaksoy1,2,4 and Faruk G¨olo˘glu2,3

Answer (score 1):

[Guillermo Valle](http://guillefix.me/cosmos/static/Algorithm%2520to%2520compute%2520LZ%2520complexity%2520measure.html) has an implementation that produces the right answers (unlike e.g. the current Wikipedia code).

For instance,

Complexity of 0001 is 2: `0 001`

Complexity of 010 is 3: `0 1 0`

Answer (score 0):

Create a binary tree where left is 0 and right is 1.  For each bit, try to find the sequence in the tree.  If it's there, concatenate the next bit, rinse, repeat.  If it's not there, add it to the tree and continue.  LZ Complexity is the total number of paths in the tree (not just # leaf nodes).

By the way, is this `homework`?

Comment: Thanks Justin for your clarification. I am still not sure if I got it right or not, but for the example I have mention in the question, if I construct the tree I end up with 8 paths ( total number of nodes in the tree minus one, the root) Is it right? I was expecting to get 6 as the answer, as I have just read (am not sure) that the LZ-Complexity should be 6 in this example! Still not clear for me how they have calculated that!

Comment: and btw, this is not my homework! ;) I need this for a very strange purpose, to be more specific, I want this to find the regularity of the patterns in the data communication between two cooperating functions in an application!!! pretty weird na? :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be relevant for you. It is parallel implementation
of an algorithm LZMP that computes the LZ-complexity
in CUDA and runs on nVidia GPU.

http://www.ariel.ac.il/sites/ratsaby/Code/LZMP.zip

Comment: could add as comment

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick in Python (from: Kaspar, F. Schuster, H. *Easily calculable measure for the complexity of spatiotemporal patterns*. Physical Review A, vol 36, n. 2, p 842.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python


def lz_complexity(s):
    i, k, l = 0, 1, 1
    k_max = 1
    n = len(s) - 1
    c = 1
    while True:
        if s[i + k - 1] == s[l + k - 1]:
            k = k + 1
            if l + k >= n - 1:
                c = c + 1
                break
        else:
            if k > k_max:
               k_max = k
            i = i + 1
            if i == l:
                c = c + 1
                l = l + k_max
                if l + 1 > n:
                    break
                else:
                    i = 0
                    k = 1
                    k_max = 1
            else:
                k = 1
    return c


def main():
    lz = lz_complexity('1001111011000010')
    assert lz == 6 
    print lz


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: This gives complexity of 010 as 2, but it should be 3?