# LZ complexity algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, compression, lzw

Could you please explain me the thing: *how does LZ complexity algorithm incorporate with data compression*? Does it (or meant to) compress data or it only estimates the number of unique substrings in vocabulary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate LZ complexity without actually doing any compression, although the calculation will look a lot like what happens when LZ-compressing the input data. See, e.g., [calculating Lempel-Ziv (LZ) complexity (aka sequence complexity) of a binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946695/calculating-lempel-ziv-lz-complexity-aka-sequence-complexity-of-a-binary-stri) where one of the answers has (non-compressing) code for calculating LZ complexity.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! But is there the other way which produces compression and calculates complexity?

Comment: I think so; if you just run a standard LZ compressor and increment a counter every time you see a bit that isn't part of a string already in the dictionary, you'll end up with the LZ complexity of the input. Or at least an approximation to that; practical LZ compressors make some approximations.